# Firebase Authorization and Standard Google App Engine - cannot login or signup

Tags: email, google-app-engine, firebase, passwords, firebase-authentication

I have a google app engine and I recently decided to add app engine to it. I have gone through the steps, have imported my google project into firebase, added all the initialization code, and some temp functions for logging in and signing up. However, the app never goes past the points where I try to log in. I have been searching everywhere and trying everything I can. I'm sure I'm just missing something small, but could use another set of eyes. Thanks.

Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Endpoints!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/base.js"></script>

    <!-- SCRIPT FOR FIREBASE -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.1/firebase-database.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/firebaseApp.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <input id="txtEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input id="txtPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password">

    <button id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-action" onclick="loginEvent()">
    Log in
    </button>
    <button id="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="signupEvent()">
    Sign Up
    </button>
    <button id="btnLogout" class="btn btn-action hide">
    Log out
    </button>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
        authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
        storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>


</div>
<div class="container">

    <form action="javascript:void(0);">
        <h2>Add Asteroid</h2>
        <div><span class="label">Name: </span><input id="asteroidName" /></div>
        <div><span class="label">Diameter: </span><input id="asteroidDiam" /></div>
        <div>Dimensions:</div>
        <div><span class="dimlabel">Length: </span><input id="asteroidLength" /></div>
        <div><span class="dimlabel">Width: </span><input id="asteroidWidth" /></div>
        <div><span class="dimlabel">Height: </span><input id="asteroidHeight" /></div>
        <div><span class="label">Mean Distance From Sun: </span><input id="asteroidDist" /></div>
        <div><input id="addAsteroid" type="submit" class="btn btn-small" value="Submit"></div>
    </form>

    <form action="javascript:void(0);">
        <h2>Refresh Asteroids</h2>
        <div><input id="listAsteroids" type="submit" class="btn btn-small" value="Refresh"></div>
    </form>

    <table id="AsteroidTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Asteroid</th>
            <th>Diameter</th>
            <th>Dimensions</th>
            <th>Mean Distance From Sun</th>
        </tr>
     </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
            google.devrel.samples.hello.init('//' + window.location.host + '/_ah/api');
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my FirebaseApp.js:

```
function loginEvent()
{   
    const email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
    const pass = document.getElementById('txtPassword');

    email.value = "HELLO";
    email.value = firebase.app().name;
    pass.value = "NO";

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
    .catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
    alert('Wrong password.');
  } else {
    alert(errorMessage);
  }
  console.log(error);
});

    pass.value = "YES"
}

function signupEvent()
{
    const email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
    const pass = document.getElementById('txtPassword');

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).catch(function(error) {
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          // ...
        });
}
```

I was changing the values of the email and password just to make sure I was reaching that point. printing out the value of firebase.app().name returns [DEFAULT]. I also made sure email/password option was selected in Firebase. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to include https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.1/firebase.js which contains all the modules needed. No need to include all the others: firebase-app.js, firebase-auth.js, etc.

Also `signInWithEmailAndPassword` and `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` accept string arguments. You are passing input elements instead. There should errors thrown in the console because of this. So instead of `email`, pass `email.value`.

Comment: holy cow thank you so much.... I can't believe i didn't do email.value and such.That was the problem. Eclipse was not outputting any errors for me, even with console.log(), so I was flailing all around. Thank you so much lol

Comment: Cool, glad I was helpful.